# How to disable postback in order to make some test with client side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

I have a LinkButton which make a postback when I click on it. I would like to do the postback if some fields are complete. I can test it with javascript but I don't know how to disable postback and make it if all my test are true.
For the moment, I have this :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lkbtnActualiser" runat="server" Font-Underline="true" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx" Text="Actualiser"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And this my js function but I don't have test for the moment :

```
function lkbtnActualiser_Click() {
    alert("test");

    return false;
}
```

How I can do it please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you make you linkbutton like:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lkbtnActualiser" OnClick="LinkButtonClick" runat="server" Font-Underline="true" Text="Actualiser"></asp:LinkButton>
```

then you can write in your codebehind

```
protected void LinkButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(test())
   Response.Redirect("~/Test.aspx");
else
   test();
}
public  Boolean test()
{
  if(...)
     return false;
  else
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will trying it :) I found it in order to solve this issue with JS.

function lkbtnActualiser_Click() {

    if (TEST...) {
        alert("something");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

<asp:LinkButton ID="lkbtnActualiser" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Test.aspx" Text="Actualiser" OnClientClick="if(!lkbtnActualiser_Click()) return false;"></asp:LinkButton>